# Derivative of Band-limited functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to answer this problem: Consider a real function f, bandlimited by frequency $\omega$, which satisfy 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2dx=c.$$
(For pure mathematicians: "bandlimited" means that it Fourier transform is supported 
on $[-\omega,\omega]$.)

Is the derivative of this function limited in absolute value? That is, is there an expression $A(\omega,c)$ for which $|f'(x)|<A(\omega,c)$ for all x?

Thank for the help!

Comment: Not sure that "bandlimited" is a math term. Can you give a definition?

Comment: In future, a question at this level might belong better on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "yes". We have
$$f(x)=\int_{-\omega}^\omega g(t)e^{2\pi itx}dt,$$
so
$$|f'(x)|^2\leq\left(2\pi\int_{-\omega}^\omega |t||g(t)|dt\right)^2\leq\frac{8\pi^2\omega^3}{3}\| g\|_2,$$
by Cauchy-Bounyakovski-Schwarz inequality. It remains to notice that $\| g\|_2=\| f\|_2$ according to Parseval . Equality when $g(t)=t$.

Comment: Could you think of a function that satisfy the equality (that is, has the maximum-possible derivative value)?

Comment: The inequality comes from the Cauchy inequality. Equality holds when the functions are equal. So take $g(t)=t$.

Comment: Isn't there a $(2\pi)^2$ missing?

Comment: I think the derivative of f(x) result with $2\pi$ inside the parentheses of the middle term of the inequality (See also answer by Josep)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your second question.

If $f(x)=\int_{-M}^M\hat f(w) e^{2\pi i wx}dw$ in $L^2(R)$, with $f\in L^2(R),$ we have

$\vert f'(x)\vert=\vert\int_{-M}^{M} 2\pi iw\hat f(w) e^{2\pi i wx}dw\vert\leq 2\pi \Vert f\Vert_2 \sqrt{2M^3/3}$

If you take now
$$f_n(w)={{\sqrt 3}\over {\sqrt 2 n^{3/2}}}({{ -n \cos(2 n \pi x)}\over{\pi x}} + {{\sin(2 n \pi x)}\over{2 \pi^2 x^2}})$$
 we have $$f_n\in L^2(R), \ \hat f_n (t)= i t  \chi_{[-n,n]}(t)$$
 Moreover $$\Vert f\Vert_2=1, \  \ \ f_n'(0)=i n^{3/2} 2\sqrt 2/\sqrt 3 \pi$$

Comment: How does this differ from what Alexandre Eremenko already said in his updated answer?

Comment: i didn't see his updated answer, I only saw his first answer.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a missing sqrt for f morm in the second equation?

Comment: Also, did you mean $f_n(x)?$